Extracting a URL from a HTTP 200 Response and redirecting to that url
I've been searching for a while but I haven't found anything that 100% matches what I would like to achieve.
I'm submitting data to an API and getting a response. I can see the submission is successful and I need to redirect to a url that's contained within the response.
Example of the response...
{ "status": "OK", "redirectUrl": "https:\/\/blalabla.com" }
These are the things I've tried...
$decodedarray = json_decode($response,true);

if($decodedarray['status'] == "OK") {
    header("Location: ".$decodedarray['redirectUrl']);
}

if($response->response->header->status == 200)
    {
        $redirect_url = $result->response->body->redirectUrl;
        
        header("Location: ".$redirect_url);
        die();
    }

if($response->response->body->status == 200)
    {
        $redirect_url = $result->response->body->redirectUrl;
        
        header("Location: ".$redirect_url);
        die();
    }

The page looks like its refreshing after the submission and sometimes I see the response in the browser. But it won't automatically redirect to the given url. The url is dynamic and changes so I can't hard code it.
I'd appreciate any pointers please. Thanks

"These are the things I've tried..." - but you've provided no analysis of why it did not work as expected / what actually happenned on the server. Most likely this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php/

After calling header("Location: ..."), use exit() to stop redirection interference.
$response = /* your response here */;

$decodedarray = json_decode($response, true);

if (isset($decodedarray['status']) && $decodedarray['status'] === "OK") {
    header("Location: " . $decodedarray['redirectUrl']);
    exit(); // Exit after redirecting
}


To check the headers your PHP script sends, you can use browser developer tools or the command line. For example, curl. This way you can see if the Location header is OK.
